# Keep only one record from left table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to get records after inner join without duplicate data from left table.

```
Parent table :
Parent id  parent name
1          Douglas 

Child table :
Parent id  child name
1             George
1             Michael
```

With classic Oracle Inner join I get this :

```
Parent id  parent name  child name 
1          Douglas      George
1          Douglas      Michael
```

But I need this result:(i need null values instead of parents names)

```
Parent id  parent name  child name 
1          Douglas      George
Null       Null         Michael
```

Of course, there are more parents and children.

Comment: PLease show what you have attempted.

Comment: The logic is not that clear to me. Do you want to see parent's informations only for the first child, based on child_id? Also, this table structure says that a guy can not be a parent and a child at the same time; is this correct for your need? At least you don't duplicate a guy in both tables

Comment: This makes no sense. If you have six unrelated parents, and three of them have children named Michael, and for each of the parents Michael is not the first child, you will get the same row in triplicate. Then: if there are six parents, and each has three children, for the rows with no parent_id and no parent_name how will you know who are whose children? And please don't say "based on the row order" as there is no such thing in a relational database. Are you asking about how to **display** the results in that way, which can be done easily in your front end, but is a different question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` or `lag()` or `lead()`, like here:

```
select case when rn = 1 then parent_id end parent_id, 
       case when rn = 1 then parent_name end parent_name, 
       child_id, child_name 
  from (select p.parent_id, p.parent_name, c.child_id, c.child_name, 
               row_number() over (partition by p.parent_id order by c.child_id) rn
          from parents p join children c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id)
```

**<sup>[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/KCYM59486)</sup>**

```
 PARENT_ID PARENT_NAME   CHILD_ID CHILD_NAME
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1 Douglas              1 George
                                2 Michael
```

Comment: very interesting...i will check that

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a right join on `child id`

```
select p.parentid,p.parentname,c.childname
from parent p
right join child c
on p.parentid=c.childid
```

Comment: You mean ... =c.ParentId ?

Comment: no. As your sample data, you need `c.childid` in join. If this is not what your want, edit the question to give more sample data and expected output.

Comment: Sorry there are not childid

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with [a CURSOR EXPRESSION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions006.htm#SQLRF52077):

```
select parent_id
       , parent_name
       , cursor ( select child_id
                         , child_name
                  from child
                  where child.parent_id = parent.parent_id )
from parent
```

How well this renders depends on the client you use to run it. Some handle the output better than others.

Alternatively you can treat it as a display issue. For instance, in SQL*Plus you could use `BREAK ON parent_id ON parent_name` to suppress repeating values. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch6.htm#i1081534).

```
select parent.parent_id
       , parent.parent_name
       , child.child_id
       , child.child_name
from parent 
     join child
         on child.parent_id = parent.parent_id
order by parent.parent_id, child.child_id;
```

To make this work you have to have ordering.

---

> "It seems more complicated than I thought. Is there other way without Cursor?"

That's because result sets are meant to be flat not jagged. Tweaking the query to implement display features often results in clunky or verbose SQL.

Talking of which, here's another solution for you:

```
with cte as (
   select parent.parent_id
          , parent.parent_name
          , child.child_id
          , child.child_name
          , row_number() over (partition by parent.parent_id 
                                             order by child.child_id ) as prn
          , row_number() over (order by  parent.parent_id , child.child_id ) as rn
    from parent 
         join child
             on child.parent_id = parent.parent_id
)
select case when prn = 1 then parent_id else null end as parent_id
       , case when prn = 1 then parent_name else null end as parent_name
       , child_id
       , child_name
from cte
order by rn
```

This generates two row numbers, one to track the parents, one to sort the entire row set.

Comment: It seems more complicated than I thought. Is there other way without Cursor?